# jQuery Server Side DataTables - Data only showing on first page

Tags: php, datatables

Hi I'm trying to use `jQuery DataTables Server Side` in my `PHP` website. I was able to display all the data, search/filter data. But its only working on the first page. When I'm trying to go to the `Second Page` and above, `No matching records found` is display and no data. Please check my below code, not sure if the problem is on my query. Thanks

**Test.php**

```
$fetch_data = $dtQuery->make_datatables();  
    $data = array();  
       foreach($fetch_data as $row)  
       {  
            $sub_array = array();
             $sub_array[] = $row['ApplNo'];
             $sub_array[] = $row['BLNo'];
            $data[] = $sub_array;  
       }
       $output = array(  
            "draw"                    =>     intval($_POST["draw"]),  
           "recordsTotal"          =>      $dtQuery->get_all_data(),  
            "recordsFiltered"     =>        $dtQuery->get_filtered_data(),
            "data"                    =>     $data  
       );  
       echo json_encode($output);
```

**ViewPage.php**

```
<table id="myTable">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>First name</th>
            <th>Last name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    </table>
```

**QueryTable.php**

```
public function make_datatables(){  


      $offset = $_POST['start'];
      $limit = $_POST['length'];
      $filter = $_POST["search"]["value"];
      $extractdata = "SELECT  *
                  FROM    ( SELECT    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY CreationDate DESC) AS RowNum, *
                        FROM      MANIFESTBOL WHERE (ApplNo LIKE '%$filter%' OR BLNo LIKE '%$filter%')
                      ) AS RowConstrainedResult
                  WHERE   RowNum >= '$offset'
                    AND RowNum < '$limit'";

             return $STH = $this->connection->query($extractdata);
      }  
    public function get_filtered_data(){  
           $filter = $_POST["search"]["value"];
           $extractdata = "SELECT  COUNT(*)
                  FROM    ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY CreationDate DESC) AS RowNum, *
                        FROM MANIFESTBOL WHERE (ApplNo LIKE '%$filter%' OR BLNo LIKE '%$filter%')
                      ) AS RowConstrainedResult";

             return $STH = $this->connection->num_rows($extractdata);
    }

    public function get_all_data()  
      {  
            $count = "SELECT COUNT(ApplNo) as count FROM MANIFESTBOL";
            $result = $this->connection->count_all_results($count);
            return $result["count"];

      }
```

**Script.js**

```
var dataTable = $('#myTable').DataTable({
        "iDisplayLength": 10,
        "aLengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 100, 500, 1000, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, 500, 1000, "All"]],
       "processing":true,  
       "serverSide":true,  
       "order":[],  
       "ajax":{  
            url:'webfiles/Test.php',
            type:"POST"
       },  
       "columnDefs":[  
            {  
                 "targets":[0],  
                 "orderable":false,  
            },  
       ]
  });
```

Comment: Its not going to work, you will need to implement every option like `sSearch`, `sSearch_*`, `bSearchable_*`, `iSortCol_*`, `iSortCol_*`, `sSortDir_*`, `iDisplayStart`, `iDisplayLength`, `sEcho` ...

Comment: @LawrenceCherone do you have any reference for that? thanks a lot

Comment: When i did it i mapped it via looking at the ajax request which exposed the params (just looking at the class I built). Though there is a lib now https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html see Server-side Script tab, if you want to know what your need to handle see:  http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/server-side

Comment: Your lucky your requirement does not include JOINed tables as well.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone still I can't work out geez. xD